# how to write and use a rule in rdf and shacl

Tags: rdf, rules, shacl

assume a rule like this:

```
if someone.height>180 then 
       someone is tallPerson
else if someone.height>155 then 
       someone is mediumPerson
else
       someone is shortPerson
```

How do I represent these rules in a shacl shape file?
and if I have data graph like this:

```
 :bob a :Person ;
      :hasHeight 185 .
```

how can I get :

```
:bob a :tallPerson .
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: I have an example on my blog of using shacl and rules: https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/03/14/rule-execution-with-shacl/

Comment: Thank you Henriette, your article is helpful. Would you please also introduce the use of sh:if or give an example of ttl?